# Can One Solve This Scary Sequence?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, sequence, word-sequence

The following terms appear in a sequence. Unfortunately, they are scrambled (both the original terms and their order).

> Theory, Policeman?, Contest, Clarice, Bad Act, One in Rome, Fashionable, Confess, Scary

Can you put them in the correct order and say why you are right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The correct order should be:

> One in Rome, Fashionable, Bad Act, Confess, Policeman?, Theory, Contest, Clarice, Scary

Why? Because:

> Each of these words or phrases represents (by word association or straightforward definition) another word, which differs from the previous by the addition of a single letter (without rearrangement):
>
>  One in Rome = **I**
>  Fashionable = **IN**
>  Bad Act = **SIN**
>  Confess = **SING** (i.e. 'squeal')
>  Policeman? = **[STING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(musician))**
>  Theory = **[STRING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory)**
>  Contest = **[STARING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staring#Staring_contests)**
>  Clarice = **[STARLING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarice_Starling)**
>  Scary = **STARTLING**